# Apache conditional header

Tags: apache, cors

I have to add the CORS header to some pages:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Is there a way to add it only for some pages? Something like **HeaderCond**?  I would like to set a regex for the affected urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's [Header directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) can take an [expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) as its 4th argument. If present, the header will be applied only when that expression is true. To have your header match URLs you could do something like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" %{REQUEST_URI}=~/\.css$/
```

The regex I used (`\.css$`) is matching files ending in '.css', but you can obviously replace that with whatever regex you need.

Comment: For me (Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)), above code generates alert saying `.htaccess: error: envclause should be in the form env=envar`.